# How to detect if a system admin reads CEO mail from outlook server?

Tags: privacy, email

A friend asked me this question yesterday. System admins are able to access outlook mail server through RDP which is part of their job.

Is it possible to detect who reads email from the CEO or someone else ?

Comment: "outlook server"? Really?

Answer (score 3):

Not reliably.
Your main problem is that the admin probably needs to access those files for legitimate reasons, and it's very hard to separate him doing routine maintenance from him actually reading the content.

If he were to read/export them through the online interface it would obviously show up in the audit logs, but for the sysadmin there are a lot of ways to read the files, and you can't reliably detect all of them.

But to set up detection where you can, you could try a combination of these:

- [Monitoring local file/folder access](http://web.archive.org/web/20131228033843/http://www.neondemon.com/archives/how-to-monitor-file-and-folder-access-on-a-windows-file-server)
- [Writing an IDS signature to detect network exfiltration](http://paginas.fe.up.pt/%7Emgi98020/pgr/writing_snort_rules.htm#content)

Monitoring local access will catch more than an IDS, but it will contain lots and lots of routine access.

For the IDS rule you'll want to detect for a unique string found in his PST file like a GUID

Comment: Adding local file monitoring and IDS doesn't really solve the problem, all it does is move the problem to the sysadmin who sets up the monitor/IDS.

Comment: The **only** sure fire way to ensure you and only you have control over who reads your email is to use end-to-end encryption, like OpenPGP/GnuPG or S/MIME.

Answer (score 2):

@J.A.K. already said it can't be done reliably.

Note that if your backups aren't encrypted, then anyone who has access to the mail server backups can also read anyone's mailbox.

There's only one reliable technical way of preventing admins from accessing files they shouldn't have access to: Don't give them access. This can be done like so:

1. Prevent admins from accessing a file by not storing it on a server that the admin has access to. Since another server will also have admins taking care of the machine, that only moves the problem from one person to another, but it might still be better from a security standpoint because create a kind of container solution - admin 1 has access to this data, and admin 2 can access this other data, but nobody can access everything.
2. As an extension of 1., you can use an external E-Mail service. Of course now you give a third party provider access to your E-Mails. Still, that might be a better risk, all in all. If you move to a very large provider, chances are there will be much less specific motive at that provider to look at your CEO's mail, and there might be policies in place that you can't afford yourself, such as very narrowly controlled and enforced access rights, encryption of data at rest and so on, which would all make it harder for an unauthorized person to steal mail. The problem: You don't really control any of these policies, and can't check whether they are actually in place and effective.
3. Use end-to-end encryption for internal E-Mail. Internally, you can probably train your people to do that; external communication is probably hopeless to secure via end-to-end encryption, because all your communication partners would need to change their E-Mail habits.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to detect who reads email from the CEO or someone else ?

To some degree, yes.  But it's going to be "expensive", and full of lots of holes.  To reliably do that would require audit trails on any machine that can access the email, encrypted backups, separating who has access to the backups from who has access to the decryption keys, and some significant added risk and maintenance costs from the added complexity.

Even after all that you might not be able to separate legitimate access from illegitimate one.  And there's still multiple avenues to get at the raw live data without being tracked.

In practice, I'd say this is rarely if ever done.  You should note that even the NSA, with bottomless budgets ultimately had to trust Edward Snowden with highly classified data.

Comment: Even then, a malicious sysadmin either has direct or indirect access to the backup keys, and copying them locally would only leave the USB manufacturer id in the logs, which he could alter. The security model was broken when the word 'admin' came along.

Comment: @J.A.K. Not if you use public key cryptography.  But there's many ways to get around the system, and it's never going to be perfect, or perhaps even "pretty good".